# Is there an option in snowflake to escape /n in an enclosed field in CSV?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to load a csv file into snowflake from an external S3 stage.
The problem seems to be that my file has a new line inside a field enclosed by "".

I created a file format for the file as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FILE FORMAT file_format
     TYPE = CSV
     COMPRESSION = AUTO
     FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '"'
     RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n'
     FIELD_DELIMITER = ','
     SKIP_HEADER = 1
     EMPTY_FIELD_AS_NULL = TRUE;

COPY INTO trans_table
    FROM  @data_stage
    FILES = ('file.csv')
    FILE_FORMAT = file_format
    FORCE = TRUE;
```

When I try to load the file in a table, an error occurs related to the row ending unexpectedly:

"End of record reached while expected to parse column"

Comment: The file format looks okay for newlines enclosed in double quotes, though you might want to use \042 instead of the double quote in the definition. Can you share the COPY INTO statement or INSERT statement you're running?

Comment: Hello, the copy into statement is pretty straight forward:    
 COPY INTO trans_table
    FROM  @data_stage
    FILES = ('file.csv')
    FILE_FORMAT = file_format
    FORCE = TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem was that I had some rows that were not enclosed by "", but they contained newlines, so that what got me the error.

The file format statement above should be enough to escape /n in strings enclosed by "".

Comment: were you able to solve it? I am having the same issue...